# RxJava - What is the difference between delay and delaySubscription?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to understand the difference between **delay** and **delaySubscription** operators.

[This documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) describes **delay** operator:

> The Delay operator modifies its source Observable by pausing for a
>   particular increment of time (that you specify) before emitting each
>   of the source Observable’s items. This has the effect of shifting the
>   entire sequence of items emitted by the Observable forward in time by
>   that specified increment

[image]

delaySubscription is described like this:

> There is also an operator with which you can delay the subscription to
>   the source Observable: delaySubscription.

[image]

However, when I tested the behaviour of these 2 operators, it seems to me they are working in the same way.

This is my observable:

```
Observable observable = Observable.just(5, 3, 4, 2);
```

Here I am using **delay** operator:

```
observable = observable.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is my observer which logs when one of its methods called

```
Observer observer = new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Log.d("RxJavaTag", "onSubscribe");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {
                Log.d("RxJavaTag", "onNext: " + o);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.d("RxJavaTag", "onError:" + e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d("RxJavaTag", "onComplete");
            }
        };
```

Here Observer is subscribing to Observable:

```
observable.subscribe(observer);
```

In result, I am getting the following log when I am using **delay** operator:

```
03-25 17:45:34.156 onSubscribe
03-25 17:45:37.160 onNext: 5
03-25 17:45:37.160 onNext: 3
03-25 17:45:37.160 onNext: 4
03-25 17:45:37.160 onNext: 2
03-25 17:45:37.160 onComplete
```

And the following log when using **delaySubscription** operator:

```
03-25 17:49:22.540 onSubscribe
03-25 17:49:25.544 onNext: 5
03-25 17:49:25.544 onNext: 3
03-25 17:49:25.544 onNext: 4
03-25 17:49:25.544 onNext: 2
03-25 17:49:25.544 onComplete
```

As you can see in logs, they are working in the same way. I could not understand the difference between them. I tried to test it with ConnectableObservable - the same behaviour.

In my understanding and as its name suggests, should not **delaySubscription** operator work in this way:

```
[SOME DELAY - FOR EXAMPLE 3 SECONDS]
03-25 17:49:25.540 onSubscribe
03-25 17:49:25.544 onNext: 5
03-25 17:49:25.544 onNext: 3
03-25 17:49:25.544 onNext: 4
03-25 17:49:25.544 onNext: 2
03-25 17:49:25.544 onComplete
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong - but I could not understand the difference. Can you please explain the difference between delay and delaySubscription?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can imagine this as a stream of a football game, and the source is emitting frames [**A hot observable**].

**Assuming a real-time stream scenario** .. In case of `delay(3 seconds)`, once you turn on the channel you'll be subscribed but will receive the first frame after 3 seconds of its actual emission, so you'll continue watching the game with 3 seconds delay.

In case of `delaySubscription(3 seconds)`, once you turn on the channel you'll wait 3 seconds (missing any frames emitted during these 3 seconds) then subscribe and start receiving the rest of the frames in real time

Comment: That's a very concise explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`delaySubscription` only affects the initial subscription. After it has subscribed to the downstream `Observable` it operates just as normal.

`delay` works on the `onNext`, `onComplete` and `onError` events, delaying those for the specified amount of time, but keeping the relative delay between them the same.

The difference would be clearer if you used a less predictable source than `Observable.just`

Comment: thank you for your answer. You wrote 'delaySubscription only affects the initial subscription'. But as you can see in logs, it is not affecting subscription. What do you mean by 'less predictable source than Observable.just'? It would be great if you set an example

Comment: Operators that change `onSubscribe` only do so going up the chain. Since your logging action is in the Observer it is unaffected. If you put the logging action in a `doOnSubscribe` operation before the delay it should be visible.

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty clear when you look at the operators one beneath the other (like you posted). In general you "loose" the red and orange marble when the subscription is delayed. Compared to delay which will give you those just with an delay.